# The target "XamlC" does not exist in the project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, msbuild

I've been working on Xamarin.Forms app and suddenly I started receiving this error **MSB4057**. I have no idea where it came from and what does it mean, but I have tried to clean, rebuild, close, reopen and even install visual studio again. I can run other projects and have no problem, also I tried to run the same project on another machine and there were no problems with it at all. The error shows that the issue is in file **Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets** line 3349 which is in MSBuild inside Visual Studio's folder.

```
<Target
  Name="Compile"
  DependsOnTargets="$(CompileDependsOn)"/>
```

Assuming that something is corrupted in my project inside of my machine, I deleted the project and pulled from the repo again, also I created a new app and manually replaced files and overwrote the dependencies, but still none of the methods help. The problem is also not related to any code changes since I tried to run previous version and they are corrupted as well.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed and what does this actually mean? I wasn't able to find much information about it on the web.

Comment: Might be related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69838817/199364). They encountered similar problem, involving current mono nuget. My vague understanding is that nuget restore tries to download from nuget source the current one, but there is some issue with it. You might be able to copy nuget versions from your working pc. Maybe edit .csproj to specify exact version to use, so doesn’t get updated. Workaround until next release of that nuget. I’m speculating, don’t fully understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

1.If the problem occurs after updating NuGet, try cleaning the NuGet cache.

2.Remove all plugins about xamarin and reinstall.

3.Delete bin and obj files android and ios. then rebuild the solution.

Comment: The thing is that as I've mentioned above the issue seems to be related to the machine I've been working on this project specifically which is extremely weird. Because when I tried to run the same project in another machine or instance it was ok. So my concerns were related to some kind of **MS Build** problems. Probably you're partially right and some packages can be related to this, but the reason why and how it happened is unknown. In my case some of the Nugets cannot be updated because some of them are not compatible with others and xamarin version.